# General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction error on Magento 2.1.2

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento2

I have problem while adding a new product in Magento 2.1.2 and I don't know how to solve it I am new in Magento. When I am adding the products it returns this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar`(`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`value`,`store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `attribute_id` = VALUES(`attribute_id`), `value` = VALUES(`value`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`)
```

> changed the
>
> ```
> innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120
> ```
>
> value in mysql config file but it is not solved my problem

any one have any other solution

Answer (score 0):

check your mysql status in phpmyadmin or in mysql commandline with `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`. You may find the query that is locking a table you want to write into.

Comment: Yes, its correct, in my case DBeaver database manager is locking my table :D